# Should there be a grace period before downvoting questions from a new user?

Tags: discussion, votes, new-users

During GIS.se's beta/post-launch, I was a believer of the a 24-hours grace period for bad questions from new users so that new users weren't immediately discouraged from participating in the GIS.se. And I commented accordingly when I saw premature downvotes.  And I was about to add comments to this question about not immediately downvoting the asker (new user).:

[I have a shapefile containing three types of polylines, how can I color each type with different colors?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23287/i-have-a-shapefile-containing-three-types-of-polylines-how-can-i-color-each-typ)

But is this still reasonable?

Or is GIS.se established and we should be downvoting immediately? It certainly seems to be the way it is on stackoverflow.com:

- [What grace period do you allow someone to reformat his question if it is less-than-perfect?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125295/149156)
- [To Downvote or Not to Downvote...or to Wait?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112659/to-downvote-or-not-to-downvote-or-to-wait)

And I'm not talking about a *grace period* system feature--only a grace period as a community *guideline*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I very much agree with user [Pekka's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125298/149804) in the thread you linked.

When I see a bad question by a new user, I try to ask myself whether it might be a language barrier problem, lack of research ("rtfm"), or "do my homework for me".

I try to help improve questions where language seems to be the problem. I don't think the other two kinds of question deserve a grace period.