# Downvoting, when is it appropriate?

Tags: discussion, votes

I've been a long time user of GIS stack. Until recently it always seemed that questions were treated with a relative level of fairness. Questions that were (probably not) written in a clear way were given the benefit of doubt and allowed to be improved (as described in the answer at [Should there be a grace period before downvoting questions from a new user?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778) -- but please note that my concern is about *all* questions, regardless of who posts them).
When truly bad questions were posted they tended to attract negative votes quickly ... which is fair.
However, there seems to be a growing trend of just downvoting anything that might not immediately make sense. This seems like bad form to me.

Many of the people who post questions here have English as a second language. Voting a question down just because its a little poorly phrased makes the site look snobby (at best).
Is there any way that people could assess a question on the merit of what is being asked, rather than just voting it down?

Answer (score 12):

With the special case of new users (perhaps with English not as their first language) addressed in a separate Q&A at [Should there be a grace period before downvoting questions from a new user?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778) my answer applies to any remaining cases of experienced and English speaking users, and when it is appropriate to downvote their questions.

The tooltip for downvoting is:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful.

I would hope those are the criteria that anyone downvoting is using to make their determination.

I think it is a sign of site healthiness when a question that shows little research effort, and/or is not clear and/or is not useful, receives early and clear feedback from the community to an asker that their question needs to be edited to improve it before it is likely to attract a quality answer, and in some cases to help it to avoid being closed.

I must emphasize that I do try to make allowance for new users and people with English not as their first language before downvoting any question or answer.

I am always surprised that many new users, and even the occasional long time user, do not take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) before asking their first question.  It is this which is designed to introduce them to the site and its protocols, and to lead them into the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help) and its advice on [How to frame a good question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question)

Answer (score 4):

I feel that the main situation that requires downvoting AN ANSWER is when it is mistaken, incorrect, dangerous or proposes a gunblazing approach without informing potential users of pitfalls.

[PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4232/8038) is very precise, covers the rest of the ground very well and i totally agree with it.